# Onclick on td wont work

Tags: javascript, onclick

Hi I am trying to get work javascript on click event on table cell, But it wont work, and I dont know why.

Please Help me!!!

Javascript:

```
function showData1(godina,mjesec,dan)
{
    alert("Godina = " + godina + ", Dan = " + dan);
}
```

Html

```
<td onclick="javascript:showData1('2013','11','21');" class="calendar-day_used">21</td>
```

Answer (score 2):

Remove the "javascript:", onclick is bound to call javascript anyway

```
<td onclick="showData1('2013','11','21');" class="calendar-day_used">21</td>
```

Put this in a blank html-file and run it

```
<script>function showData1(godina,mjesec,dan)
{
    alert("Godina = " + godina + ", Dan = " + dan);
}</script>
<table><tr><td onclick="showData1('2013','11','21')" class="calendar-day_used" style="display:block; cursor: pointer;">21</td></tr></table>
```

I have tested it on three different versions of IE as well as firefox and chrome. It. Works.

Answer (score 0):

This is working fine here: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8ngZP/)

What you need to do is remove `javascript:` from `javascript:showData1('2013','11','21');`